# How to access the HttpServerUtility.MapPath method in a Thread or Timer?

Tags: .net, asp.net, timer, httpcontext

I use a `System.Timers.Timer` in my Asp.Net application and I need to use the `HttpServerUtility.MapPath` method which seems to be only available via `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`.
The problem is that `HttpContext.Current` is `null` when the `Timer.Elapsed` event fires.

Is there another way to get a reference to a HttpServerUtility object ? 
I could inject it in my class' constructor. Is it safe ? How can I be sure it won't be Garbage Collected at the end of the current request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 144, accepted):

It's possible to use `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()` instead of `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()`

I haven't tried it yet in a thread or timer event though.

---

Some (non viable) solutions I considered;

- The only method I care about on `HttpServerUtility` is `MapPath`. So as an alternative I could use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and build my paths from this. **But this will fail if your app uses virtual directories** (Mine does).
- Another approach: 
  Add all the paths I need to the the `Global` class. Resolve these paths in `Application_Start`.

Comment: Note however that the above does not work in later versions of IIS. In IIS7 the application start may be called outside of an http request. That is, the code example. I'm sure HostingEnvironment.MapPath() will still work like it did before.

Comment: But HostingEnvironment.MapPath() gives an error if you pass it and empty string in order to get the folder path directly...
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(""); -> works
HostingEnvironment.MapPath(""); -> raises error

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if this will solve your virtual directories issue, but I use this for MapPath:

```
public static string MapPath(string path)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);

    return HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + path.Replace("~", string.Empty).Replace('/', '\\');
}
```

Comment: path.Replace("~", string.Empty)
should be path.Replace('~', '.')

Answer (score 13):

HostingEnvironment isn't the perfect solution because it's a very difficult class to mock (see [How to unit test code that uses HostingEnvironment.MapPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740498/how-to-unit-test-code-that-uses-hostingenvironment-mappath)).

For those who need testability, a better way might be to create your own path-mapper interface as proposed by https://stackoverflow.com/a/1231962/85196, except implement it as

```
public class ServerPathMapper : IPathMapper { 
 public string MapPath(string relativePath) { 
      return HostingEnvironment.MapPath(relativePath); 
 } 
}
```

The result is easily mockable, uses HostingEnvironment internally, and could even potentially address [ase69s's concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111927/how-to-access-the-httpserverutility-mappath-method-in-a-thread-or-timer#comment12074999_112220) at the same time.

Comment: This allowed me to provide an implementation for path resolution for a Web API project without requiring a dependency to System.Web or System.Net in the library it was referencing.  +1

Comment: Thumbs up for DI and Testability of this approach

Answer (score 2):

Can you not call the MapPath function before starting the timer, and simply cache the result? Is it absolutely neccessary to have the MapPath call inside the tick event?

Answer (score 2):

When the timer elapse, there is no current HTTP context. This is because the timer events are not related to a specific HTTP request.

What you should do is use HttpServerUtility.MapPath where HTTP context is available. You can do it in one of the request pipeline events (such as Page_Load) or in a Global.asax event such as Application_Start.

Assign the MapPath result to a variable accessible from the Timer.Elapsed event, where you could use Path.Combine to get the location of a specific file you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for why it is null at that time (if you think about it), is that the timer elapsed event doesn't occur as part of a HTTP request (hence there is no context). It is caused by something on your server.