# How do I retrieve the HttpContext properties when it returns null?

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext

I am doing some asynchronous work on a separate thread using:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()
```

and in this separate thread, I need to call `HttpContext.Current` so that I can access:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache  
HttpContext.Current.Server  
HttpContext.Current.Request
```

However, `HttpContext.Current` is null when I create this separate thread.

#### Question

How do I create a new thread so that `HttpContext.Current` is not null? Or is there another way I can access the Cache, Server, and Request objects?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd try not to hold a reference to an object that depends on the ASP.NET stack like the HttpContext. If you need to do some work in a different thread, it's because you don't want to wait in the ASP.NET one till your task is finished. And maybe the Request/Context/Session is terminated while your thread is not.

You should pass an object with the data needed for your thread.

Answer (score 37):

You can access the ASP.NET cache with **HttpRuntime.Cache** even when you don't have a HttpContext, but unfortunately you cannot access Server or Request.

If you think about it, this make sense - you are not serving any page so you don't have a request.

Comment: Good to know, this is what I needed for my particular conundrum, thanks!

Comment: Thumbs up! (Y). HttpRuntime.Cache helped saving my time alot. thanks

Comment: See also [HostingEnvironment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/112220/222481) for server-oriented calls (eg. `HostingEnvironment.MapPath`).

Answer (score 3):

1- Add bottom code in `<system.serviceModel>` in Web.config file:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

2- Add bottom code after NameSpace in web service file:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

3- Rebuild web part project.
Done!

[reference](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/97983.aspx/1)

Answer (score 1):

For HttpContext.Server services you can use HttpServerUtility class.
For the Cache you can use HttpRuntime.Cache, as it has been said above.
For the request object you can pass the data from the Request to the thread when it is created. Things like Request.QueryString or Request.Form... or whatever.

Comment: To initiate an instance of HttpServerUtility outside of a web request, use: 
new HttpApplication().Server
(via http://britishinside.com/archive/2005/08/20/HttpServerUtility.aspx)

Some features won't work though. For example, Server.MapPath doesn't. But as a workaround use System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a thread pool implementation [here](http://www.bearcanyon.com/dotnet/#threadpool) that provides propagation of the calling thread's HTTP context. I haven't used it yet but I plan to.

Answer (score 0):

If the separate thread is trying to access those objects, then yes they will be null. Those objects are scoped at the thread level. If you want to use them in a new thread you will have to pass them into the method/class where you need them.

Typically ASP.Net doesn't allow you to spawn new threads... Here is a [post](http://csharpfeeds.com/post/5415/Dont_use_the_ThreadPool_in_ASP.NET.aspx) on the subject.

Here is a nice write up on [threading in ASP.NET from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164128.aspx).

Comment: The post on not creating threads  in ASP.Net says nothing of the sort.  It simply states you shouldn't use the ThreadPool to create your threads, and that you should manager them yourself.