# Get the file path of current application's config file

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, app-config

The reason I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956629/determine-if-app-is-winforms-or-webforms) is that I wanted to create a helper class for Remoting instantiation, and wanted to pass the appropriate app.exe.config (or web.config) file path to the `RemotingConfiguration.Configure` method, depending on the caller.

Is there a way I could get the name of the **config file** for **both Win and Web apps** without checking if the application is Web or WinForms?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've used

```
string folder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null ?
    System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_data") :
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

without problems, but maybe there is some corner cases I don't know about...

Comment: I have capital letter "D" for "App_Data".

Answer (score 30):

You can use the [`ConfigurationFile` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile) on the [`SetupInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.setupinformation) for  [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.currentdomain).

This will get either the web.config or and app.config (yourprogram.exe.config) location.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
```

Comment: Honestly, this answer strikes me as pretty self-explanatory; the member names are incredibly descriptive.

Comment: Note this is not supported in .NET Standard 2.0

Answer (score 3):

To find the location of executing application

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

Don't know about web case.

Comment: I presume you meant `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".config"`, but actually I need a solution which would work for both apps.