# How to get the full path of a file inClass library?

Tags: c#-4.0, filepath, class-library

I am writing a class library and referring it in a WCF Service.

In this class library , i need to get the physical path of the app.config file.

It is working when hard coded with full physical path. But, i do not want to do this way.

**Please see my code:**

```
  private static void loadConfig()
        {
            strConfigpath = "app.config";
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(Path.GetFullPath(strConfigpath)) );
        }
```

I tried using `Path.GetFullPath()`. But, it is giving **wrong** result.

I cannot use `Server.MapPath()` since it is not a **web service** or **web application.**

How to do this ? Ant thoughts or suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the FullName property

```
    string fileName = "app.config";
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
    string fullname = f.FullName;
    f.DirectoryName; //This will give the folder path which is having the file
```

try something like this,

```
string folder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null ?
System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_data") :          System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

refered : [Get the file path of current application's config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957042/get-the-file-path-of-current-applications-config-file)

Comment: can you tell me your original and the path returned by this code

Comment: C:\Users\343434\Desktop\Final\MyWCFService\Utilities\app.config

Comment: This is the actual physical path in the class libarary project

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\app.config.. This is the path..i am getting by using above ?