# How to unit test code that uses HostingEnvironment.MapPath

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I have some code that uses `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` which I would like to unit test.

How can I setup `HostingEnvironment` so that it returns a path and not `null` in my unit test (mstest) project?

Comment: Why would you have a code that depends on `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` in an ASP.NET MVC application where you have access to objects like `HttpServerUtilityBase` which allow you to achieve this and which can be easily mocked and unit tested? Maybe you could show this code and explain the scenario so that we can improve it?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Because I didn't know of `HttpServerUtilityBase`. Can you add an example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why would you have a code that depends on HostingEnvironment.MapPath in an ASP.NET MVC application where you have access to objects like HttpServerUtilityBase which allow you to achieve this and which can be easily mocked and unit tested?

Let's take an example: a controller action which uses the abstract Server class that we want to unit test:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var file = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/foo.txt");
        return View((object)file);
    }
}
```

Now, there are many ways to unit test this controller action. Personally I like using the [MVcContrib.TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper).

But let's see how we can do this using a mocking framework out-of-the-box. I use Rhino Mocks for this example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index_Action_Should_Calculate_And_Pass_The_Physical_Path_Of_Foo_As_View_Model()
{
    // arrange
    var sut = new HomeController();
    var server = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
    var context = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<HttpContextBase>();
    context.Expect(x => x.Server).Return(server);
    var expected = @"c:\work\App_Data\foo.txt";
    server.Expect(x => x.MapPath("~/App_Data/foo.txt")).Return(expected);
    var requestContext = new RequestContext(context, new RouteData());
    sut.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, sut);

    // act
    var actual = sut.Index();

    // assert
    var viewResult = actual as ViewResult;
    Assert.AreEqual(viewResult.Model, expected);
}
```

Comment: What if we are testing a `ApiController` and not `MVC` one?

Comment: What if we're not testing a controller but a utility class?

Comment: What if you're testing code that's not yours and you want to refector it based on tests that don't exist?

Answer (score 4):

Well I was writing a test today for code that I don't control and they used

```
    private static String GetApplicationPath()
    {
        return HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath.TrimEnd('/');
    }
```

so here is a C# reflection hack to set that value

```
var path =  "/aaaa/bb";

HostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;
if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted.isFalse())
    new HostingEnvironment();

hostingEnvironment = (HostingEnvironment)typeof(HostingEnvironment).fieldValue("_theHostingEnvironment");

var virtualPath = "System.Web".assembly()
                   .type("VirtualPath").ctor();

virtualPath.field("_virtualPath", path);
//return virtualPath.prop("VirtualPathString");                
//return virtualPath.prop("VirtualPathStringNoTrailingSlash");                 

hostingEnvironment.field("_appVirtualPath", virtualPath);
//hostingEnvironment.field("_appVirtualPath") == virtualPath;

return HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath == path;       

//using  System.Web.Hosting
```

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what mocking or isolation framework you are using. You might want to look into either a) creating a wrapper type around the static property that can be mocked, or b) using a framework which can mock static properties - e.g. [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) or [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As i faced same issue i changed my code bit.
**From**

```
strhtmlTemplate = File.ReadAllText(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(Lgetfilepath.CVal));
```

**To**

```
strhtmlTemplate = File.ReadAllText(HttpContextFactory.Current.Server.MapPath(Lgetfilepath.CVal));
```

For Unit test

```
public HttpContextBase mockHttpContextBase()
        {
            var moqContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            var moqRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
            var moqServer = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
            var moqPath = new Mock<ConfigurationBase>();
            moqContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(moqRequest.Object);
            moqContext.Setup(x => x.Server.MapPath(@"~\Data\xxxxxxx")).Returns(Environment.CurrentDirectory+@"\xxxxxx");                
            setupApplication(moqContext);

            return moqContext.Object;
        }
```

Now we while Writing TestClass you need to refer above method to mock. Hope it will helpful for your TestCases.

```
MockDataUT mockData = new MockDataUT();
var mockRequestContext = new HttpRequestContext();
HttpContextFactory.SetCurrentContext(mockData.mockHttpContextBase());
```

Answer (score -4):

Just use this code..

Make a new folder name Reference in root directory and added your file inside this folder.

Use this

```
public static XElement GetFile()
{
    HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest("", "http://www.google.com", ""), new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));

    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    var file = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\\") + "abc.xml";
    doc.Load(file);
    var e = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(doc));
    return e;
}
```