# Entity Framework - How to get relative file path in seed method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Why is filePath null? Any ideas on how to get the relative filePath?

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MvcProject.Models.FileDb>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        // code here is not relevant to question
    }
    protected override void Seed(MvcProject.Models.FileDb context)
    {    
        string filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/File.txt");

        // read File.txt using filePath and update the database
    }
}
```

I have the above code in Configuration.cs file in Migrations folder created when entity framework is set up on an ASP .NET MVC project

When I run "Update-Database -Verbose" in Package Manager Console I get an error that filePath is null.

If I manually set filePath with an absolute URL to the file:

```
string filePath = "C:/Users/User1/My Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/MvcProject/Content/File.txt";
```

Everything works fine.

Obviously the goal is to have a relative path to enable work with different developers on different setups.

Truth be told all I need is the file - not necessarily the path. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the filepath is null, or the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` and you have an exception ?

Comment: Aristos, I know filePath is null (or System.Web.HttpContext.Current is). What I don't know is why nor a way to get the filePath in the seed method

Comment: If you do not know what is null, then you probably not found how to solve it. I think that you call that not from a page and the `HttpContext` is null and that the issue here. At the end your question must be accurate and not let us imaging the real problems - of course you can follow that only is you seek for solutions.

Comment: I posted an answer to your question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323437/how-to-get-file-path-in-entity-framework-seed-method-without-httpcontext-execut/20070329#20070329

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I use this function to map paths inside the Seed method, not very clean but it works:

```
private string MapPath(string seedFile)
{
    if(HttpContext.Current!=null)
        return HostingEnvironment.MapPath(seedFile);

    var absolutePath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath; //was AbsolutePath but didn't work with spaces according to comments
    var directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(absolutePath);
    var path = Path.Combine(directoryName, ".." + seedFile.TrimStart('~').Replace('/','\\'));

    return path;
}
```

then just call it using:

```
   using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(MapPath("~/Data/MyFile.csv")))
```

Comment: On my dev machine, this puts %20s in the path, so if you have spaces in your folder names it fails.

Comment: You, are a beautiful person... My goodness I've been looking left right and centre for this bloodpepfoefoisjk;gfiorjeogjersgio. THANKYOU!

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 *blush* :)

Comment: You can use .LocalPath insted of .AbsolutePath to get spaces instead of %20

Comment: @WiebeTijsma, you are my savior ! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As I say , I belive that you call it from a page and the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is null, because `MapPath` function never return null with a not null input - so you get an exception there.

Try that alternative:

```
string filePath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "/Content/File.txt";
```

or

```
string filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/File.txt");
```

Related question: [How to access the HttpServerUtility.MapPath method in a Thread or Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111927/how-to-access-the-httpserverutility-mappath-method-in-a-thread-or-timer)