# How to reference a disk file during a code-first migration Seed method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using ASP.Net MVC5 and Entity Framework with code-first migrations.

During the Seed method for my migration Configuration class, I want to access a read from a data file I have in my project. How can I specify the path so that it will be found both in development and deployment?

The following does not work (of course).

```
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
         BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
         using (Stream binaryStream = File.OpenRead("Data/seed.bin"))
         {
            ...
         }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: An alternative idea: put it in as a resource.

Comment: I used the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323437/how-to-get-file-path-in-entity-framework-seed-method-without-httpcontext-execut/20070329#20070329