# Data files not there when publishing through Azure (Microsoft Bot Framework)

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I'm trying to read from a text file that contains some data in my bot. I have the file in my Visual Studio solution and the bot is able to read the data fine when I am using the Emulator.

However, when I publish, it says that the file doesn't exist (IO.DirectoryNotFoundException) and gives this path as the path it's looking at (my file is in the Data\Holidays folder in Visual Studio):

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\Data\Holidays\Holidays.txt
```

Is the path different when it's published? Do I have to upload the text file to Azure manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you include the file as a part of your project? (after build, check your bin folder). If not, then please include your  file.

For more details you may try these links

1)[Entity Framework - How to get relative file path in seed method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260975/entity-framework-how-to-get-relative-file-path-in-seed-method)

2)[ASP.NET Web application file path (Publish on Azure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443680/asp-net-web-application-file-path-publish-on-azure)